# how to set transparent background to android tab widget,

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Is it possible to set a transparent background to android tab widget,I used the below code to set the tab background image

```
   Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bgImage);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

[image: this background image has a transparent in top]

but the problem,is i can see a black line not a transparent, can someone help me on to fix this..!

[image]

Comment: r u get answer for ur question.I have same problem...

Comment: found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to know here.

First, you set a background programmatically with

- setBackgroundColor(int) (if you're setting it to a color)
- setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) (if you're setting it to a Drawable type; this is deprecated, and was replaced by .setBackground(Drawable))
- setBackgroundResource(int) (for setting a resource from R.java)

Second, you set transparency with the alpha channel of a hex value. Eg. if you want to set your background to red with 20% transparency, you would use the hex value `#CCFF0000`. In this example, CC is the hex number for 255 * 0.8 = 204.

I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to achieve here as I can't tell whether `drawable` is created from an XML file or from an image file. If bgImage is an XML file, however, you should be able to solve your problem by applying the type of hex value I described above to the appropriate area of your XML file with `android:background=""`

Comment: bgImage is coming from sqlite Database (all the images saved in sqlite). I just changed the deprecated method to setBackground, Image having a transparent in top, but once it set to tabWidget showing a black as above.

Comment: Is the camera icon that extends above your blue line a part of bgImage? It looks like it is pushing the sun image out of the way from below. If this is the case and drawable extends all the way to the top of the camera icon, then that black band is actually a part of the image itself. The only way to change the black portion of the image to transparent is to edit the image itself using an image editor like Photoshop. I'm no graphic designer, but I would probably just draw in the tips of the sun's rays and then fill the black region with the background yellow from the above image.

Answer (score 0):

create a transparent png image, just a blank image. Make this image the background for the bar.

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundDrawable(R.id.mytransperentimage);
```

Comment: created image is transparent in top and bottom is blue,

Comment: Comment taken from an NAA of omi_android: *It does not work in api level 14*